# A replacement for consistently

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> There are still a lot of features to add to this project which I will *consistently* do in whatever free time I get.

The way this sentence sounds doesn't seem right to me.

I looked for other synonyms of *consistently* like ***constantly*** and ***continually***, but they also didn't sound right.

Is there any other word I can use in that place?

Comment: Take the mind off *consistently*, which is not the right word here. Look for alternatives that fit what exactly you mean: *regularly*? *steadily*? ...? Good Luck.

Comment: To me what sounds wrong is the use of "in" in the phrase "consistently do in."  It should be with.  The only problem with consistently is that if you don't follow up with what you are promising, it could be an issue.

Comment: What don't you like about *consistently*? The definition of the first sense at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consistently) is: *marked by harmony, regularity, or steady continuity : free from variation or contradiction*. Is that what you're trying to express, or is it something else?

Comment: If you drop the word *consistently* and replace it with the null word the sentence reads well and, I think, expresses your intentions clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you drop **consistently ... in whatever free time I get** and then say **... which I will do *whenever* I have free time**.

The version with **whenever** conveys the idea you're after with "consistently", is far more idiomatic, and isn't as wordy.

Answer (score 0):

You could say ***methodically*** or ***systematically***.

I personally prefer ***systematically***:

> in a focused, consistent, and methodical way:
>
> - The report will help me analyze deficiencies within the company and ***systematically*** implement action plans to address them over time. ([Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/systematically))

---

Note that if this is is an academic context, *in whatever free time I get* looks too informal for your context. I would suggest your sentence be rewritten as:

> Many features still need to be added to this project which I will do ***systematically*** *whenever time allows*.

Answer (score 0):

> There are still a lot of features to add to this project which I will
> **conscientiously** do in whatever free time I get.

**Conscientiously** (adv.)

> In a conscientious manner; in accordance with one's conscience or
> one's sense of duty; on grounds of conscience; **well and thoroughly;
> scrupulously.** (OED)

*Conscientiously* packs in a lot of bang for your buck. It can refer to your work attitude as well as your commitment to the quality of your work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to work it in, but the word **periodically** might better describe the part of the sentence "whatever free time I get"

Webster.

Synonyms of periodically
1
: at regular intervals of time
2
: from time to time : FREQUENTLY

Answer (score -3):

***PERMANENTLY*** is appropriate in your case.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permanently):

***PERMANENTLY***

Adverb

: in a permanent manner

: in a way that continues without changing or ending

: in a way that is not brief or temporary

// The restaurant closed permanently in May.